# Incorrect rendering of two overlapping sprites

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glsl

Here is the problem, when drawing multiple sprites (textured Quads)
the sprite on the front, clips the back sprite, and I won't be able to display behind it to the user.

My expected output is to display both textures correctly same as left part of the picture shown below: (the right side is incorrect)

[image]

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Here is my code:

Draw function:

```
    shader_begin(self->shader);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glBlendEquation(GL_ADD);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    shader_end();
```

Vertex shader:

```
  gl_Position = view_projection * world * vec4(point, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) if you use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending). The fragments are discarded by the Depth Test before they can be blended, a fragment that is not discarded during the depth test will be blended. So it depends on the order in which the objects are drawn. If you use blending, you have to deactivate the depth test and draw the objects sorted by depth from back to front. This can also mean that the meshes have to be divided into their primitives and the primitives have to be sorted or even primitives have to be split.
See also [Transparency Sorting](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting), [OpenGL depth sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305911/opengl-depth-sorting) and [OpenGL: Transparent texture issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954668/opengl-transparent-texture-issue).

If the alpha value is only 0 or 1, then an alternative solution would be to discard fragments depending on their alpha value instead of blending them. Disable blending, but `discard` fragments in the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations). e.g.:

```c
void main() {

    [...]

    if (color.a < 0.5)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: I can consider discarding (masking) great solution, but sadly I have translucent sprites ..
 
about that, I have disabled the depth test, and certainly there is nothing but two sprites on the scene, one facing forward, and another rotated 45 degrees,  the order is, sprite[0] -> sprite[1]  and no fully opaque objects in the background,
as you can see, half of the sprite renders correctly, the issue is another side(right side) 
when disabling the depth test, sprite[0] on right side renders first which is also incorrect, but left side, remain correct

Comment: @Aryan As I said before, you have to disable the depth test and to render the sprites in the correct order from back to front. There is no alternative. I can understand that you don't like this solution, but there is no other.

Comment: you mean splitting these two Quads into 4 quads by their intersection edge? and then render them from back to front? That is going to be far more disappointing for me

Comment: @Aryan Yes, I know that's disappointing. But since you are not using a render engine, but OpenGL directly, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: anyway, how does game engines achieve this? as it is easy as dropping two planes into the scene.. any idea how they actually work?